# Starting an Activity for result in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have been struggling with this case for a long time now, any help would be appreciated.

I have a main activity with 3 fragments (in other words I have an activity with three tabs). On the third fragment I have a button starts a new activity through intent. That new activity is a QR scanner so it basically calls the camera and waits until camera finds appropriate and valid QR code. How do I get the result back to my fragment?

My button's *onClick* method which located in *onCreate* method in Fragment3 which extends Fragment class:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ZBarScannerActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

My MainActivity's onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
    {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
        {
            String result = data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT);

        }
    }
}
```

From this on I cannot figure out how to get this result back to Fragment3's onActivityResult method. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry=getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getActivity().getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()-1);
String str=backEntry.getName();
Fragment fragment=getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(str);
```

This will give you the latest instance of the fragment. Make sure that you added your backstack entry like this.

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(someName);
```

Or while adding the fragment you can provide a tag. Like below

[public abstract FragmentTransaction add (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I am getting *runtimeexception* error:
ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, List) line: 3205 
ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread$ResultData) line: 3248 

This is my updated onActivityResult method (note that I am using support library for fragments):

`FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry = (BackStackEntry) getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(2);
    String str=backEntry.getName();
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(str);
    
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

Comment: post complete stcktrace

Comment: I have narrowed the error to what can I see is a NullPointerException on my Fragment's onActivityResult method.

It says that Intent "data" is null but on the other hand the main activity's onActivityResult "data" is not null. Now I do not have a clue why this is happening. I am calling super.onActivityResult().

Comment: Okay, I have fixed the error. It wasn't Intent data's fault but my code that followed. Your code works but it is simpler to call super.onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) in your main activity thread and then you just override the method in your fragment.
Thanks!